# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'linkWithCredential' of null

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I can't link two email accounts using Firebase. 
It sends back to me an error -"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'linkWithCredential' of null" !
Can you help me?

My code is :

```
<script>
        function linknew(email, password){
            var authcredential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
            var auth = firebase.auth();

            auth.currentUser.linkWithCredential(authcredential).then(function(usercred) {
                var user = usercred.user;
                console.info("Account linking success", user);
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Account linking error", error);
            });
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your currentUser variable might be not initialized, hence it is null and you cannot access the property linkwithcredential, to guard yourself from this situation, you can add an observer to your auth object, like this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

check [firebase: manage users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users), check the first star note as well:

> Note: currentUser might also be null because the auth object has not finished initializing. If you use an observer to keep track of the user's sign-in status, you don't need to handle this case

Answer (score 0):

Check whether page elements which you are trying to access in JS is loaded before scripting.

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   // code here
});
```

or

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  // code here
});
```

[Check this Link for more info](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/running_your_code_at_the_right_time.htm)

Comment: It's generally better (appears faster) to use `document.ready` for scripts that don't need to wait for all images to load.